# SQL query to count number of different values

Tags: mysql, sql

```
x y

A P
A P
B P
B Q
```

Hi, I need a query to return for all unique values of x, how many different y's. So for the above data it would return:

```
x count
A 1
B 2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use GROUP BY and [`COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct):

```
SELECT x, COUNT(DISTINCT y) AS cnt_y
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY x
```

Result:

```
x    cnt_y
A    1
B    2
```

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable (x VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, y VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO yourtable (x, y) VALUES
('A', 'P'),
('A', 'P'),
('B', 'P'),
('B', 'Q');
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the simple case for a `GROUP BY` statement.

Here's some code:

```
SELECT x, COUNT(DISTINCT y) AS y
FROM table
GROUP BY x;
```