# query to count number of different values?

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, distinct, ms-access-2003

I have a table in MS Access 2003 that looks like this:

```
    *url            id*
    example.com    red
    example.com    blue
    example.com    blue
    other.com      red
    other.com      orange
    more.com       blue
```

For each URL I want to know how many unique id there are.  so in this case the result should be:

```
    *url             count of distinct id*
    example.com          2           (because red and blue are the only values)
    other.com            2
    more.com             1
```

This is very similar to [SQL query to count number of different values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253214/sql-query-to-count-number-of-different-values) except the solution in that case does not work because it relies on `COUNT DISTINCT`, but that is not supported in Access.  I have tried to look up alternative ways of doing count distinct in Access but I'm afraid I don't understand the answers.

So I guess this problem can be summarized as "how to simulate count distinct in msaccess".

I would greatly appreciate it if someone can give me a hint.

Comment: +1 For a well phrased question (and searching the archives for answers first! :).

Comment: Good question, I was struggling with this exact problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work in MS Access 2003 (*I just tested it*):

```
SELECT url, count(id) as CountOfId
FROM
(
   SELECT distinct id, url
   FROM yourtable
) x
GROUP BY url
```

In this you get the distinct id and url in a subquery and then you count that result.

Comment: Thanks very much, that does work.  I removed the "x" which I believe is a typo (?) and it does the job great.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: The x was an alias for the subquery. I am used to SQL server which requires it, but it did work in access with the alias

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing it without using the distinct keyword. (Although it looks like later versions of access would support it):

```
SELECT t.url, Count(*) AS distinct_id_count
FROM
(
    SELECT url
    FROM *source_table_name_here*
    GROUP BY url, id
) AS t
GROUP BY t.url
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, t.url;
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this if I have any issues with the previous solution.